# Jave Type Parameter Method and Constructor Problem

Tags: java, function, types, parameters

I have these classes:
- Class A is an interface with only one Abstract Method "M1" with a type                       parameter
- Class B implements A 
- Class C is abstract class
- Class D extends Class C

On class B i Override Method M1 and tries to create an C objects but its not working

```
public interface A{ 
    public abstract <R> void M1(int a, int b, R ress);
}
public class B implements A{ 
    public <B> void M1(int a, int b, B ress){
        D itsd = new D(int a, int b, ress);
    }
}
public abstract class C{ 
    int a, b;
    public C(int a, int b){
        this.a=a;
        this.b=b;
    }
}
public class D extends C{ 
    B c;
    public D(int a, int b, B c){
        super(a, b);
        this.c=c;
    }
}
```

Im getting a error with this suggestion : Change Constructor D(int a, int b, B c) to D(int a, int b, B c) idk why, Im sorry if this problem seems obvious to you but im new to all this Typed Method

Comment: `B c` is not always same type as `B ress`. You can try to parametrize `D` class or its constructor for `c` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class B implements A{ 
    public <B> void M1(int a, int b, B ress){
        D itsd = new D(int a, int b, ress);
                                     ^^^^of any reference type.
```

Here the type parameter `B` is hiding (I think that's the right term) the class `B`. `ress` could be of any type specified by the caller.

Did you mean:

```
    public <R> void M1(int a, int b, R ress){
```

Later on...

```
public class D extends C{ 
    B c;
    public D(int a, int b, B c){
```

Here `B` is class `B`.

I strongly suggest avoiding single letter class names, or otherwise wildly flouting the Java naming conventions.

Comment: Yes, "hiding" or "shadowing" is the term.

Comment: @chrylis Aren't hiding and shadowing slightly different things? I could just look it up in the JLS, but I'd only forget again.